C++ Modules: Best practice for importing standard library
I'm trying to understand the difference between two inclusions of standard headers in C++20 in Modules world. The flowing are the two options:
1.
export module my_module;
import <iostream>;

export void do_something() { 
   std::cout << "hello";
}




module;

#include <iostream>;

export module my_module;

export void do_something() { 
   std::cout << "hello";
}

I think in this case 1 and 2 are identical, but perhaps 1 is considered superior since if I add other #includes before #include <iostream> in option 2, such includes that define macros may change the behavior of <iostream>. While introducing a global module fragment in option 1 and adding include will not change the behaviour of import <iostream>. Am I right?
For completeness, in C++23 I would do:
export module my_module;
import std;

export void do_something() { 
   std::cout << "hello";
}


So perhaps best practice for modules is to use C++23?  :-)

I revised the question. I need to use c++20 and I'm trying to understand the difference between 1 and 2.

Only ever include/import what you actually use, is a good first principle.

Note: import std; is going to be accepted in C++20 mode by all three major implementations. https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/3945

"I think in this case 1 and 2 are identical, but perhaps 1 is considered superior". No they are not identical. As for superiority, it depends on what your implementation offers. If your implementation can support option 1, then go with option 1. (See second comment)

"adding include will not change the behaviour of import". If you do it right then no. The preprocessor simply includes the content of the module included.

You can import a standard library module if your implementation provides a standard library module else you’ve got to #include the good ol header files and let the preprocessor do what it has been doing best since PL/1 and Algo —pun intended.
Is it best practice to use C++20 modules? Of course! Faster compilation times? You bet. But you cannot completely go without header files. At least not anytime soon…

assert() is a macro and so far we haven’t agreed on a non-macro replacement for it.

The first illustration:
export module my_module;
import <iostream>;

export void do_something() { 
   std::cout << "hello";
}
Will compile iff the implementation provides standard library modules. Else, fallback to the second illustration:
module;
#include <iostream>;
export module my_module;

export void do_something() { 
   std::cout << "hello";
}

Obligatory nitpicking: Do not import the std module if you want to ensure that standard-library facilities not suitable in a context aren’t deliberately or accidentally imported.
export module my_module;
import std;

export void do_something() { 
   std::cout << "hello";
}

Any example of when accidentally imported parts of the standard library can cause a problem?

@Eugene there are issues like this that keep coming up but slow but surely they will all get fixed.
